# Easy question regarding multivariable calculus

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

We know $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is differentiable at $a$ if there exists linear $T$ such that

$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0) - T(h)}{||h||} = 0$$

Why does this imply that

$$ \lim_{h \to 0} (f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0) - T(h)) = 0 $$

??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It follows from continuity of multiplication.

Since 
$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0) - T(h)}{\|h\|} = 0$, and
$\lim_{h \to 0} \|h\| = 0$, then 
$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0) - T(h)}{\|h\|} \cdot \|h\| = (\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0) - T(h)}{\|h\|} ) \cdot ( \lim_{h \to 0} \|h\| )  = 0.0 = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varepsilon >0$.

If $$||\frac{f(x+h) -f(x) - T(h)}{||h||} || < \varepsilon$$
then
$$ ||{f(x+h) -f(x) - T(h)} || < \varepsilon$$
as soon as $||h|| \le 1$